# Column name naming conventions and best practices

Tags: database-design, join, naming-convention

I would like some expert opinion on best practices when it comes to **column naming**.

The background is that [according to Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Equi-join), the following syntax,

```
SELECT ... FROM Employees JOIN Timesheets USING (EmployeeID);
```

is more efficient than

```
SELECT ... FROM Employees JOIN Timesheets ON (Employees.EmployeeID = Timesheets.EmployeeID);
```

However, the `JOIN ... USING` syntax only works of *all primary key columns have globally unique names*. Thus I wonder if this is considered The Right Thing to do.

Personally, I always used to create tables with PK column `id`, and foreign key column `othertable_id`. But that way it's not possible to use `USING` or `NATURAL JOIN`.

Any links to design styles or best practice guides for table design would be appreciated, too!

Comment: Wikipedia is wrong. The first version is by no means more efficient than the second. Under the hood the database will create absolut identical queries

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This has been asked before on SO.

Where you have common and very ambiguous names, then prefix with table name. That is, anything you're liable to have to alias in almost every query.

So for an Employee table I'd have

```
EmployeeID
EmployeeName
Comment
Salary
StartDate
EndDate
InsertedDateTime
...
```

And Wikipedia actually says:

> The USING construct is more than mere syntactic sugar, however, since the result set differs from the result set of the version with the explicit predicate. Specifically, any columns mentioned in the USING list will appear only once, with an unqualified name, rather than once for each table in the join.

That is one less column. You'd never use `SELECT *` anyway so the point is moot...

Comment: I hadn't thought of searching SO - silly me. Do you have links to any particularly good SO questions? Anyway, thanks, I shall stick to the "unique ID" naming henceforth!

Comment: @Kerrk SB: actually, I haven't. I tend to ignore them because each one gets answered or closed quickly :-) Sorry

Comment: I would like to see those similar questions on SO, if anyone can dig up a link. I came here because I couldn't find a question there, and I was sure it'd have been asked already. I immediately found this question though.

Comment: It was on programmers.SE. A nice big bun fight for you... http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/114728/why-is-naming-a-tables-primary-key-column-id-considered-bad-practice/114732#114732

Answer (score 6):

In the book [SQL Antipatterns: Avoiding the Pitfalls of Database Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1934356557), using `id` is not recommended, and I would agree with the author.

This is a particular problem when you are doing complex reporting and need more than one `id`, as you then have to alias those columns. Using `<tablename>_id` makes it easier to identify the correct foreign key to join to  (as they have the same name) and makes errors from joining to the wrong column less likely.

That said, many databases don't support the `USING` syntax, which makes the problem a non-issue for those databases. Nor do many databases support using a natural join which I would also not recommend using, as the join could change if the table structures change. For example, you might a column called `modified_date` to both tables, you would *not* want to join on those columns but the natural join would attempts do so.

Answer (score 4):

It is better to explicitly give table name and column name like Employees.EmployeeID with expressions where a join exists